# Queue order of background task

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I have a windows phone 8.1 app that has several background tasks. They all are called by 15-minute time triggers. So how can I assure that they are executed one after the other?

For example first the background task is called that updates some date, and only after that the background task is called that updates a live tile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that's currently not possible. Your background tasks will be executed in a certain time frame but there is no guarantee that there's an explicit order.

But if you know that you want to do things in a sequential order why not do everything from one background task? You can always update a live tile manually from a background task (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj991805.aspx).

Comment: I use custom tile in my app. So i afraid that if i do everething in one task it go out of time or memory limits.